# Extracting data from void Array not happening correctly

Tags: arrays, c, sockets, struct

I'm trying to receiving an int array from sockets, The array im sending from host is

```
    cont[0]++;
    cont[1]=1;
    cont[2]=2;
    cont[3]=3;
    cont[4]=4;
    cont[5]=5;
    cont[6]=7;
    cont[7]=8;
    cont[8]=8;
    cont[199]=199;
```

and I'm sending like this

```
void *data1 = &cont;

    datalen=sizeof(cont);
    if (sendto(sd, data1, datalen, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&groupSock,sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
    {
        perror("sending datagram message");
    }
```

my struct to hold receive data is

```
typedef struct SenderData {
    unsigned short CommandCode;
    int DataSize;
    void* Data;
   } SenderData;

SenderData rcv;
```

Data size is the size in bytes of Data coming from socket

I'm reading data from socket by this function, my data is sent to socket serially, like , command code, size, data ......

I'm sending an int array of 200 elements from host

```
int Read_packet(int CSPL_Socket, void *buf,int datalen)
    {

        if (read(CSPL_Socket, buf, datalen)<0)
        {
            CSPL_SOK_ERROR(-6);
            close(CSPL_Socket);
            exit(1);
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

my function call from  main for read is

I get the type of data from socket

```
        Read_packet(skt,&code,sizeof(code));
```

I get the size of data in socket here

```
        Read_packet(skt,&size,sizeof(size));
```

Im getting size as 800, which is the size of an int array with 200 elements sent from host

I change the order here

```
        rcv.CommandCode = ntohs(code);
```

i change the order for size

```
        rcv.DataSize = ntohl(size);
```

I allocate memory for storing data

```
        rcv.Data = malloc(rcv.DataSize);
```

here I'm assuming I'm getting an int array from host

I'm reading data from socket

```
        Read_packet(skt,&rcv.Data,rcv.DataSize);
```

Im checking data size here

```
        printf("data size is %d\n",rcv.DataSize);
```

I'm trying to print first element of rcv.Data)

```
        printf("data  is %d\n",(int*)rcv.Data);
```

I'm trying to print secondelement of rcv.Data)

```
        printf("data  is %d\n",(int*)rcv.Data+1);

        fflush(stdout);
```

but my print is not happening as expected, its just adding 1 to the previous data

Comment: This is absolutely wrong: `Read_packet(skt,&rcv.Data,rcv.DataSize);`. That should be `Read_packet(skt,rcv.Data,rcv.DataSize);` . Note the second argument. Also, neither `(int*)rcv.Data` nor `(int*)rcv.Data+1` are correct as a `printf` arguments to `%d`. Those are *pointer to int*, and the argument expected is `int`. you're probably confusing `scanf` with `printf`. Indexing would make much more sense, and fix the prior problem in the process. I.e. `((int*)rcv.Data)[0]` , `((int*)rcv.Data)[1]` etc.

Comment: @ whozCraig Im new to c, but my ` rcv.Data` is actually void , so how can i print it ? or do i have to move it to any other variable before printing? can you help me to cast that `rcv.Data`to an int array?

Comment: Look carefully at *everything* I just said as it pertains to your code.

Comment: @ WhozCraig  when i try the indexing type , i get ` 0 [main] udpexx1 470 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to udpexx1.exe.stackdump`

Comment: You didn't look carefully enough. The *first* thing in that comment is a *huge* problem, one critical to the point of invoking undefined behavior by memory overreach.

Comment: @WhozCraig yup my mistake, now its working  thanks a lot,